# Caching objects to filesystem - java/android serialization performance

Tags: java, android, json, caching

I am implementing content caching in my android application, and i have implement it for now with JSON content saving to file, as shown below:

```
(1) Network request
(2) Fetching JSON response
(3) Serializing JSON to model class
(4) Saving JSON to cache
(5) Returning model class to initial requester.
```

I think steps above cannot be any faster, because i already have deserialized object in JSON form for network response.

Now lets suppose that our device is disconnected, and we make a network request:

```
(1) Network request (NotConnectedException throws)
(2) Reading JSON content from cache
(3) Serializing JSON content to Model class
(4) Returning Model class as response to initial requester
```

Now my question. How can this be any faster?

1. In first example, i suppose that saving JSON to cache could be done asynchronously while returning Model class.
2. More important, regarding serialization in second example, what type of content instead of JSON should be used for caching to filesystem, so that step (3) in second procedure executes faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the performance of JSON acceptable for most use cases, even running on a cellphone.

If you are observing performance problems in your application, I'd first look for caching opportunities;  each object should only be de-serialized once per session with the user and then stored in the memory of the application.

Some faster alternatives to JSON parsing include:

1. Java Serializer writes the state of Serializable Java objects to a byte array, which can then be stored to disk or sent over a network. Faster than JSON since it read/writes raw data and doesn't require parsing.
2. Protobuf writes the state of Java objects to a byte array also. It's been heavily performance tuned and should be faster than the Java Serializer for most applications.

The builtin Java serializer is faster than JSON. You ca